# NHibernate map to inconsistent Data

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate to map a DataModel. Unfotunatley the DataBase contains some inconsistent data due to lack of keys/constraints. Currently I am stuck with an m:n mapping where some keys on the map Table reference missing data.
Here is some sample Data:

```
Table: Foo
id  Value
0   A
1   B
2   C

Table: Bar
id  Value
10  X
20  Y
30  Z

Table: Map
foo_id  bar_id  amount
  0       10        2
  0       11        4
  1       12        5
  2       20        8
```

I want to fetch all the Foo, that also have a Bar. In (T)SQL i would just use a join. I've tired a couple of mappings (like references + nullable, etc), but since the mapping table contains a key, NHiernate seems to expect an entity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the link table contains "missing" ids, why not just delete them, and put constraints back ?

Comment: @mathieu Either that or construct a View and map your entities onto it.

Comment: I can't perform modification on the Database, due to a very high impact risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `not-found="ignore"` attribute (`NotFound.Ignore()` in Fluent).